# C# Graphics.DrawString RectangleF Auto-Height: How to find that height?

Tags: c#, height, drawstring

I am writing text over an image using Graphics DrawString method, binding my text with a RectangleF. Here is my code:

```
//Write header2
RectangleF header2Rect = new RectangleF();
header2Rect.Width = 600;
header2Rect.Location = new Point(30, 105);
graphicImage.DrawString(header2, new Font("Gotham Medium", 28, FontStyle.Bold),brush, header2Rect);
//Write Description
RectangleF descrRect = new RectangleF();
descrRect.Width = 600;
int measurement = ((int)graphicImage.MeasureString(header2, new Font("Gotham Medium", 28, FontStyle.Bold)).Height);
var yindex = int.Parse(105 + header2Rect.Height.ToString());
descrRect.Location = new Point(30, 105+measurement);
graphicImage.DrawString(description.ToLower(), new Font("Gotham", 24, FontStyle.Italic), SystemBrushes.WindowText, descrRect);
```

This works for some cases (ie. when `header2` is only 1 line long), but my `measurement` variable only measures the height of the Font, not the whole `DrawString` rectangle. I do not want to set a static `header2Rect` height because the heights change depending on that text.

yindex does not work because `header2Rect.Height = 0`. Is there a way to see how many lines my `header2` is?

Do I just need to do `MeasureString` width and divide that by my boundary rectangle width, then multiply by the `MeasureString` height? I'm assuming there is a better way.

Thanks

[EDIT] It looks like the height is actually 0 but the text just overflows outside, but the width still constricts the text-wrapping. I just did some math calculations to find the height, but I wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are never setting your rectangle heights:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  string header2 = "This is a much, much longer Header";
  string description = "This is a description of the header.";

  RectangleF header2Rect = new RectangleF();
  using (Font useFont = new Font("Gotham Medium", 28, FontStyle.Bold))
  {
    header2Rect.Location = new Point(30, 105);
    header2Rect.Size = new Size(600, ((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(header2, useFont, 600, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(header2, useFont, Brushes.Black, header2Rect);
  }

  RectangleF descrRect = new RectangleF();
  using (Font useFont = new Font("Gotham Medium", 28, FontStyle.Italic))
  {
    descrRect.Location = new Point(30, (int)header2Rect.Bottom);
    descrRect.Size = new Size(600, ((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(description, useFont, 600, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(description.ToLower(), useFont, SystemBrushes.WindowText, descrRect);
  }

}
```

Comment: In my c++ project, only `StringFormat::GenericDefault()` works correctly instead of `StringFormat::GenericTypographic()`. I'm not sure what's the reason.